# user friendly keyboard based on input type

Tags: android, mobile, types, input, keyboard

Is this a feature provide by OS, or it is based on the browser or is it based on device?

On iphone it shows respective keyboard depending on the field type like url/number/email.

check this http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201004/html5_input_types/

Can this be enabled for andriod?

Comment: you can do that by setting `android:inputType` attributes in xml...

Answer (score 0):

You can set **`android:inputType`** attribute in layout.xml.
Such as below:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Comment: Thanks Brian/Paresh. Just to confirm that my questions is for web and not for an android application. Can this solution be used for web pages?

Comment: I will select the accepted answer if I can get my problem solved. Where is layout.xml stored?

Comment: it stored at project name/res/layout/....xml. It is not named layout.xml, it is named by yourself, usually the default is main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

We can check the `keyboard support with input type` using the following link if you want to enable the respective keyboard with webview.

http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html